# Add Image Size in Wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add images sizes on my wordpress site. I searched alot and tried too many solutions but couldn't work for me can anyone help me on this, it will be appreciatable. Thanks in advance. I have added this code in my functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );

function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'slider_image_desktop' => __( 'slider_image_desktop' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_setup_theme' );
function wpse_setup_theme() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'slider_image_desktop2', 60, 60, true );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone i solved my problem. I changed my some lines of code to

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_setup_theme' );
 function wpse_setup_theme() {
     add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
     if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
       add_image_size( 'slider_image_desktop2', 60, 60, true );
      }         
    }
```

It made the thumbnail then for retrieving i didn't use function for get image thumb because i am using **Advanced Custom Fields** so in **wp admin** in my **acf fields group** i just checked my image uploader's return value as **image array** and i just got full array of the uploaded image with my defined size. there was no need to use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` or `wp_get_attachment_image` function to fetch the image..

Thanks everyone for your help may this answer will help someone who will have been the same problem...

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$attachment_id = get_field('field_name');
$size = "slider_image_desktop2"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
// url = $image[0];
// width = $image[1];
// height = $image[2];
?>
<img class="image-class" alt="" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
<?php
```

Comment: i am not using it for featured image i have a custom field for image and i want thumbnail for it. @jaydip

Comment: If you have custom field so when in back-end open a popup for select image, there will be a dropdown for image size at right side, where you found "slider_image_desktop2" option select it.

Comment: there is no drop down for sizes.

Comment: are you used WordPress image upload?

Comment: i'm using **advanced custom fields** image uploader

Comment: Go to "Custom Fields" from menu select your "Field Groups", Edit it  Edit your Image field. here you can see "Preview Size" options, select your size. and don't forgot to save it.

Comment: This is just for admin. not for front end fetching

Comment: Try this:

`$attachment_id = get_field('field_name');
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'slider_image_desktop2' );`

Comment: I have changed the answer check it.

Answer (score 0):

just copy and paste on your theme function.php file

```
add_image_size( 'img-cropped', 198, 198, true );// you can change the size
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selected self answer was an absolute life saver, and got me to the point of what I was trying to do - but I had to make one small addition to get the custom image size in the backend page editor "add media" options:

```
function nmg_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'social-icons' => __('Social Icon'),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'nmg_setup_theme' );
function nmg_setup_theme() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
        add_image_size('social-icons', 9999, 60, false);
    }
    add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'nmg_custom_sizes' );
}
```

It's your function, but with the function to add the custom size to image_size_names_choose - but after theme setup (what was stopping it from working for me before).

Might be useful to someone...